# htaccess redirect using OR and NC

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, case, case-sensitive

I would like to know if I can do this redirect where I have the domain: example.com be non case sensitive along with the or statement for the IP. Both work indpendently of each other but not together?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Flags should be listed together separated by comma -- exactly the same way how it's done in RewriteRule itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Another approach:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com|123\.45\.67\.89) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```